# Use Case and if to check values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do some calculated column, my scenario is like the below example.

```
e.g:       Whenever col1 is 'Yes', check Col2, if it has any value then calculated column will be 'True'.
           Whenever Col1 is 'No', then calculated column will be 'Unknown'.
           Whenever col1 is 'Yes', check Col2, if it is null then calculated column will be 'False'.

Col1     Col2    CalculatedColumn
Yes      123        True
No       null       Unknown
yes      null       False
```

Any help how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `case`:

```
select (case when col1 = 'Yes' and col2 is not null then 'True'
             when col1 = 'No' then 'Unknown'
             when col1 = 'Yes' and col2 is null then 'False'
        end) as calculated_column
```

This can be simplified to:

```
select (case when col1 = 'Yes' and col2 is not null then 'True'
             when col1 = 'Yes' then 'False'
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as calculated_column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE..WHEN` clause to meet this requirement. Converting your requirements in `CASE..WHEN` clause -

```
case when col1 = 'Yes' and col2 is not null then 'True'
when col1 = 'Yes' and col2 is null then 'False'
when Col1 = 'No' or col1 is null then  'Unknown' end as calculated_col
```